# Mahout missing method under version 0.7

Tags: mahout

I'm reading the book 《Mahout In Action》 and i'd like to try the code myself.

But i found lots of the code can't run(Most of the issues are method can't be found).

1、RandomSeedGenerator.chooseRandomPoints(pointVectors, k); chooseRandomPoints can't be found.

2、new Cluster(v, clusterId++, measure); the constructor can't be found.

there are many of these kind of issues.

Can anyone tell me how to find those methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book was written & tested for Mahout 0.5. You can look onto `mahout-0.7` branch in repository with [examples for book](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA).

Comment: https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch09/KMeansClustering.java 

The code didn't update.

Comment: you need to switch to `mahout-0.7` branch! For example, https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/mahout-0.7/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch09/KMeansClustering.java